# mysql calculation results are the same

Tags: mysql, database

i have the following query:

```
select v.vehicle_id, 
       v.year, 
       v.make, 
       v.model, 
       v.mileage, 
       count(distinct o.order_id) as order_number, 
       sum(s.labor_hour*labor_cost_per_hour+part_cost) * 
       count(distinct vo.order_id) as vehicle_cost

   from tbl_vehicle_order vo
  inner join tbl_vehicle v 
    on vo.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
  inner join tbl_order o
    on vo.order_id = o.order_id
  natural join tbl_customer c
  natural join tbl_service s
  natural join tbl_rate r
where 
      s.rate_id = r.rate_id 
  and vo.order_id = o.order_id 
  and vo.vehicle_id=v.vehicle_id
group by v.vehicle_id;
```

the result is like this => [image]

update: 
after i edited my code, it seems the result didn't change too much. 
here is the updated code:

```
 select v.vehicle_id, v.year, v.make, v.model, v.mileage, count(vo.order_id) as order_number, sum(s.labor_hour*r.labor_cost_per_hour+s.part_cost) as vehicle_cost
 from tbl_vehicle_order vo, tbl_vehicle v,tbl_order o,tbl_customer c,tbl_service s,tbl_rate r, tbl_order_service os
 where vo.order_id = o.order_id and vo.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id and os.service_id = s.service_id and s.rate_id = r.rate_id
 group by v.vehicle_id
 order by 1;
```

updated result:
  [image]

i think there is some errors in my calculation part. anyone would like to point out my errors? Thanks!

Comment: The `count(distinct)` gives the hint.  You have duplicate rows, because you are joining two different dimensions at the same time and getting a cartesian product for each vehicle.  You need to do the aggregation in a subquery.

Comment: Are you sure you want NATURAL JOINs? It seems redundant to have the WHERE clauses. While redundant logic won't cause problems, are there other columns (like id) that it could be using as JOIN columns?

Comment: @AgRizzo if i don't use natural joins, how can i get the s.rate_id and  s.labor_hour? I am not really know how to do the aggregation function in the subquery

Comment: Regarding Natural Joins: Just use INNER JOINs (like you did for the vehicle and order tables) and explicitly state how the tables relate (as found in your WHERE clause)

Comment: @AgRizzo but for the table 'c' and 's' there don't have same attributes. how can we use inner joins

Comment: @AgRizzo i updated my code, but it seems the result didn't change too much (made a mistake in my calculation form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It assumes the schema you described in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634496/mysql-multiple-sum-calculation-wrap-up)

```
SELECT v.vehicle_id, 
       v.year, 
       v.make, 
       v.model, 
       v.mileage, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT vo.order_id) as unique_orders, 
       SUM(order_summation.order_cost) as sum_of_all_orders
FROM tbl_vehicle_order vo
INNER JOIN tbl_vehicle v 
  ON vo.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
JOIN (
    SELECT os.order_id as order_id
      , SUM(s.part_cost + s.labor_hour*r.labor_cost_per_hour) AS order_cost
    FROM order_service AS os
    JOIN service AS s
     ON os.service_id = s.service_id
    JOIN tbl_rate AS r
     ON r.rate_id = s.rate_id
    GROUP BY os.order_id) AS order_summation
  ON order_summation.order_id = vo.order_id
GROUP BY v.vehicle_id, 
         v.year, 
         v.make, 
         v.model, 
         v.mileage;
```

Comment: does JOIN do the same thing as NATUAL JOIN, but it can give the ON condition?

Comment: A NATURAL JOIN is an INNER JOIN which the server determines which columns to use in the ON clause (it chooses column names that both tables have in common) {And JOIN is identical to INNER JOIN}

Comment: what if I only want to find the highest cost of vehicle_cost? I should  add a WHERE section and explicit the ALL keyword?

Comment: Adding MAX(order_summation.order_cost) to the outer query's SELECT will provide that vehicle's most expensive order's cost (not the most expensive service cost within an order)

Comment: after i add the MAX function, it still display ever summation; but i only want the highest summation. what should i do?

Comment: Do you just 1 row with the results from the above query that is the row with the largest `sum_of_all_orders`? If so, put this at the bottom of the query (before the semicolon) `ORDER BY sum_of_all_orders DESC LIMIT 1`